# Push string to JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a json of the below format

```
{
    "name": "Stub",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/thing/1/4"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

I would like to add the below part to my json

```
"queryParameters": {
            "Accept": {
                "equalTo": "xml"
            }
        }
```

so my final outcome is of the below format

```
{
    "name": "Stub",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/thing/1/4",
        "queryParameters": {
            "Accept": {
                "equalTo": "xml"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

I tried the below but it doesn't seem to help, I also tried to parse which didn't help either

```
obj['theTeam'].push("queryParameters": { "Accept": { "equalTo": "xml" } });
jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: `push()` is an array method but you are working with an object literal not array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
obj["request"]["queryParameters"] = { "Accept": { "equalTo": "xml" } }
```

Comment: Or `obj.request.queryParameters = ...`

Comment: But wouldn't this need the queryParameters key to be present in the JSON already ?

Comment: No, it will create it or override an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I sugget to use your json like a object to access to the attributes into it:

```
// Try edit msg
var obj = {
    "name": "Stub",
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/thing/1/4"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
};
var partToAdd = {
            "Accept": {
                "equalTo": "xml"
            }
};
obj.request.queryParameters = partToAdd;
console.log(obj);
```